# SmartGit and Apache httpd: Error HTTP 403

Tags: git, apache, http, webserver

I've made git HTTP server by using this configuration. Git it pull works perfectly, but push throwing me 403 HTTP error. I don't know how to fix this error, but I really want do git server without SSH.

virtualhost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>
    DocumentRoot    "%pathToVRoot%/repos/"
    ServerName      git.domain.tld
    UseCanonicalName Off
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT %pathToVRoot%/repos/
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAlias /git/ %sprogdir%/git/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /git-receive-pack$
    RewriteRule ^/git/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]
    <Directory "/">
        Options All +Indexes
    </Directory>
    <Directory "%sprogdir%/git/git-core*">
        Options ExecCGI Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from env=AUTHREQUIRED
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        AuthUserFile %sitedir%/git/users.cfg
        AuthGroupFile %sitedir%/git/groups.cfg
        Require group admin
        Satisfy Any
    </LocationMatch>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </LocationMatch>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-upload-pack$">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here the information of request fail

> fatal: unable to access
>   'http://username@git.domain.tld/git/someRepo/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 403 Pushing to
>   http://username@git.domain.tld/git/someRepo/

Comment: For some reason it's worked now. idk what happened to server, but now push works perfectly